# How can i get values from json and display them in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to get json from a web page. The json on the page is in the format

```
[{"ID":"151032",
  "user":"UsersName",
  "message":"This is a message.",
  "date":"1293452007",
  "replies":"1",
  "categories":false,
  "categoriesArray":[],
  "lat":"0.000000000000000",
  "lng":"0.000000000000000"}]
```

How can I get `user`, `message`, `ID` and `replies` from the JSON and display it on another webpage via javascript?

Example: hello UsersName your Id is: 151032 and your message is: This is a message. it has 1 replies.

**note: there will be multiple sets of this i.e.**

```
[{"ID":"151032",
  "user":"UsersName1",
  "message":"This is a message.",
  "date":"1293452007",
  "replies":"1",
  "categories":false,
  "categoriesArray":[],
  "lat":"0.000000000000000",
  "lng":"0.000000000000000"},
 {"ID":"151033",
  "user":"UsersName2",
  "message":"This is another message.",
  "date":"1293452007",
  "replies":"2",
  "categories":false,
  "categoriesArray":[],
  "lat":"0.000000000000000",
  "lng":"0.000000000000000"}]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox#Parsing_JSON.c2.a0strings) and then access the properties like normal object properties. E.g.

```
var msgs = JSON.parse(json);

for(var i = 0, l = msgs.length; i < l; i++) {
    var msg = msgs[i];
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = 'Hello ' + msg.user + ' your Id is: ' + msg.ID + 'and your message is: ' + msg.message + ' it has ' + msg.replies + ' replies';
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/MWXHF/)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick reply. Is it possible to retrieve the JSON from a webpage for example http://stackoverflow.com/jsonstuff.json

Comment: @user556396 generally you would retrieve the JSON with AJAX requests.

Comment: @AJ00200: The JSON object is available in most browsers now afaik. If not, one can always use http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: @AJ00200 Would that work even if the JSON is on a different server?

Comment: @user556396: Then you'd need to use JSONP: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP, to circumvent the same-origin policy (but the server has to support it, if not, no chance).

Comment: @Felix Kling what do you mean by the server having to support it?

Comment: @user556396: It has to return the response as a JSONP response.

Comment: Not to be a pain, but what about $.getJSON ?

Comment: @user556396: First, this is a jQuery function, if you use jQuery then you can use it. It can make a JSONP request for you, but nevertheless, the server has to support it. See http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/:  *The way JSONP works is simple, but requires a little bit of server-side cooperation.*

Comment: OK, if i use the jQuery can i store the server response in a variable?

Comment: @user556396: Of course. You can even store the response if you don't use jQuery.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be as simple as i thought to store it in a variable how does one come about doing this?

Comment: @user556396: Well it depends on how you get the response. With jQuery, the response is passed to the callback. With normal XMLHttpRequest, the response is in `responseText` I think. And once again: If you try to access external server you won't get any response.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not safe, you can eval() the JSON data (but this could be a security issue for your users, so it would be best to use a parsing library). After eval()ing it, you can access the data like data[0]["ID"]

You can get a JSON parser here: http://www.json.org/js.html