# How to retrieve values from JSON object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i get values from json and display them in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4549173/how-can-i-get-values-from-json-and-display-them-in-javascript)

I have a JSON String which will contain SOAP Message content. This is my JSON string:

```
{
   "xml":{

   },
   "SOAP-ENV:Envelope":{
      "@attributes":"....."
   },
   "SOAP-ENV:Body":{
      "@attributes":{
         "bill":{
            "customerDetil":{
               "customerFirstName":{
                  "#text":"Mahes"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

This is what I am doin in javascript:

```
var jsonText = xmlToJson(xmlhttp.responseXML);
             var myjson = JSON.stringify(jsonText);
                alert("JSON"+myjson);

function xmlToJson(xml) {
      // Create the return object;
      var obj = {};

      if (xml.nodeType == 1) {

        if (xml.attributes.length > 0) {
        obj["@attributes"] = {};
          for (var j = 0; j < xml.attributes.length; j++) {
            var attribute = xml.attributes.item(j);
            obj["@attributes"][attribute.nodeName] = attribute.nodeValue;
          }
        }
      } else if (xml.nodeType == 3) {
        obj = xml.nodeValue;
      }

      if (xml.hasChildNodes()) {
        for(var i = 0; i < xml.childNodes.length; i++) {
          var item = xml.childNodes.item(i);
          var nodeName = item.nodeName;
          if (typeof(obj[nodeName]) == "undefined") {
            obj[nodeName] = xmlToJson(item);
          } else {
            if (typeof(obj[nodeName].length) == "undefined") {
              var old = obj[nodeName];
              obj[nodeName] = [];
              obj[nodeName].push(old);
            }
            obj[nodeName].push(xmlToJson(item));
          }
        }
      }
      return obj;
    };
```

Please tell me how to retrieve each value from my JSON string in javascript. For example `CustomerFirstName`.

Thanks, 
narayanan

Comment: You know, it would be much easier to simply format the JSON object and then use the `code` tag.

Comment: With due respect, you've asked **twenty-seven** previous questions and you've been using the site for **eight months**, you really should be formatting code and markup correctly by now. Not doing so is just disrespectful to the community. There is all sorts of information on the Ask a Question page about how to format things.

Comment: Sorry for the late response in formatting the code

Comment: @NarayananS: You can use this tool to format and validate JSON code: http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 3):

Well, you either have a JSON *string* or a Javascript *object*. There is no such thing as a "JSON object" - JSON is a string notation for encoding a Javascript Object.

If you have a JSON string, you need to turn it into a Javascript Object - search SO for numerous examples.

If you have a Javascript object, you can access attributes via the dot notation, or array notation. E.g.

```
var obj = { 'foo' : 'bar', 'foo2' : { 'foo3' : 'bar2' }};

obj.foo; // 'bar';
obj['foo']; // 'bar';
obj.foo2['foo3']; // 'bar2';
```

Answer (score 1):

Parse the JSON string first:

```
var msgs = JSON.parse(json);
```

Since JSON strings are simply dictionaries/associative arrays, you can just get the values in javascript by doing something like:

```
var value = msgs["key"];
```

In your case, it seems like the value is nested inside multiple dictionaries, so perhaps something like:

```
var customerName = msgs["SOAP-ENV:Body"]["@attributes"]["bill"]["customerDetil"]["customerFirstName"];
```

Comment: Thanks for all but this is not working in my case.I will update my code for further info what I am doin

Comment: anybody having any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html)  and [json guide](http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/01/27/json-javascript-tutorial/). This might help you