# Getting error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, json, soap

i am successfully able to get response from wsdl using my client side code by checking chrome dev tool feed retrieve success and various fields like `objid`, `personid`, `personname`, `persongroup` displayed in chrome dev console. but `resultset` retrieval is displayed with the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

i need only personid and name to be displayed

main.js

```
currentPage = {};

currentPage.init = function(){
    WL.Logger.debug("MainPage :: init");
};

function validate(){

    var username=$('#username').val();
    var password=$('#userpwd').val();

    busyIndicator.show();

    var params = {
            "process": {"username":username,"userpwd":password}
    };
        var invocationData = {
                adapter : 'SoapAdapter1',
                procedure : 'userlogin_ep_process',
                parameters : [params]
            };
        //{"process":{"username":"$('#username').val()","userpwd":"$('#userpwd').val()"}}
        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
            onSuccess : loadFeedsSuccess,
            onFailure : loadFeedsFailure
        });
    }

    function loadFeedsSuccess(result){
        WL.Logger.debug("Feed retrieve success");
        busyIndicator.hide();

    alert(result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.PERSON_ID);
    //alert is priniting the value its working
    displayFeeds(result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse);

    }

    function loadFeedsFailure(result){
        WL.Logger.error("Feed retrieve failure");
        busyIndicator.hide();
        WL.SimpleDialog.show("Inquiry", "Service not available. Try again later.", 
                [{
                    text : 'Reload',
                    handler : WL.Client.reloadApp 
                },
                {
                    text: 'Close',
                    handler : function() {}
                }]
            );
    }

        function displayFeeds(result){
            var ul = $('#mytable');
       //here i get length undefined error
            for (var i = 0; i < result.responseJSON.length; i++) {

                var li = $('<li/>').html("PERSONID:" +result[i].PERSONID);
                 li.append($('<li/>').html("PERSONNAME:" +result[i].PERSONNAME));

                 li.append($('<hr>'));
                 ul.append(li);
           }
        }
```

index.html

```
<label>username</label> <input type="text" id="username"><br><br>
<label>password</label> <input type="text" id="userpwd"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="login" onclick="validate();">
<ul id="mytable"></ul>
```

The response:

```
{
   "Envelope": {
      "Body": {
         "processResponse": {
            "ERROR_CODE": "S",
            "ERROR_MSG": "Login Successful",
            "GROUPS_ID": "76721",
            "PERSON_ID": "309236",
            "PERSON_LOGIN": "Y",
            "PERSON_NAME": "Welcome! ashanka",
            "PERSON_ROLE": "Y",
            "PERSON_UID": "1014336",
            "client": "http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessUserLogin",
            "xmlns": "http:\/\/xmlns.oracle.com\/InternetMobile\/AbsManagement\/BPELProcessUserLogin"
         }
      },
      "Header": {
         "FaultTo": {
            "Address": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/08\/addressing\/anonymous"
         },
         "MessageID": "urn:C9C4DB207D5211E5BF9B25E60F40847D",
         "ReplyTo": {
            "Address": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/08\/addressing\/anonymous"
         }
      },
      "env": "http:\/\/schemas.xmlsoap.org\/soap\/envelope\/",
      "wsa": "http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2005\/08\/addressing"
   },
   "errors": [
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "responseHeaders": {
      "Content-Length": "1017",
      "Content-Type": "text\/xml; charset=utf-8",
      "Date": "Wed, 28 Oct 2015 09:03:42 GMT",
      "SOAPAction": "\"\"",
      "X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID": "9e10a9dcf92c80fa:-8e91c30:150a34b187a:-8000-0000000000053e79",
      "X-Powered-By": "Servlet\/2.5 JSP\/2.1"
   },
   "responseTime": 106,
   "statusCode": 200,
   "statusReason": "OK",
   "totalTime": 122,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

Comment: cant get u can u brief ????

Comment: Provide your project where the error is reproducible. Upload it to Dropbox or Google Drive.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6kfKZmuMpIscGVnc0xpeHluOVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @IdanAdar hey found anything ???

Comment: when i can get solution can i post it again

Comment: where is the solution u have marked other one as duplicate ???

Comment: You are asking the same question. You will stick to one question. When people have the time, they will look at your question.

Comment: no offense but you people only said to open up questions in stackoverflow. and i need to develop an wsdl application and have so much doubts so help needed

Comment: Put alert(JSON.stringify(result)) *before* calling to displayFeeds (meaning, in loadFeedsSuccess(). What do you get? You can also use console.log instead and check it using Chrome DevTools when previewing the application.

Comment: i get response  message from the adapter

Comment: Great. Now *mention* is the response? That's the structure of it... which you need in order to navigate inside to be able to use .length. Update the question.

Comment: response is based  on my input from the clientside it responds correct message from wsdl but i want it to be printed on my html page

Comment: David. Replace "alert" with "console.log", check what is the response in the Chrome DevTools, COPY THE RESPONSE and paste it in your question. The response is an object. It has a STRUCTURE. By inspecting the structure, it will be made possible to understand how to navigate it in order to display it in the HTML. Get it?

Comment: i have pasted wsdl to adapter response above because from chrom devtools i cant able to post here because its not aligned but same msg is what i get

Comment: Now look at the structure of it. starting experimenting with it... for example, try printing result.Envelope.Body.PERSON_NAME and so on....

Comment: i tried the above in displayfeed now it says Body is undefined

Comment: Have you googled how to retrieve values from json that has soap message in it? there are numerous examples online. Here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767401/how-to-retrieve-values-from-json-object-in-javascript

Comment: no i wl try tat and later update here

Comment: @IdanAdar any solutions i have tried many but cant get output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handling JSON response from the soap wsdl in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33429313/handling-json-response-from-the-soap-wsdl-in-javascript)

Comment: hey man i have updated my question .now i can get personid as an alert message but displayfeed shows length undefined error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "responseJSON" in the object that you have receive, and this is why the error is failing on "length" is undefined: `for (var i = 0; i < result.responseJSON.length; i++)`. Remove responseJSON and use something like: [How to get object length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533192/how-to-get-object-length) or a different approach.

Comment: alert(result.responseJSON.Envelope.Body.processResponse.PERSON_ID) by this way only i can get the person id from the response message so i tried that.even though i remove response Json from the for loop i get length undefined.but i found that return response is not array of values as it returns in { } and not [] so the reason length is undefined arises maybe but i do no

Comment: Yes, it is not an array. Use something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533192/how-to-get-object-length